# Can't debug variable received from Channel in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

A have a Kotlin Channel like below. When I put a breakpoint at the Log line I want to be able to see the test variable in Android Studio, but I can not.

```
 val channel = Channel<Int>()
 launch {
     val test = channel.receive()
     Log.d(test.toString()) <--- Breakpoint set here
 }

 launch {
     channel.send(1)
 }
```

This is shown in the Android Studio debugger when I stop at the breakpoint.

```
this = {Test$test$8@7232} 
   $channel = {RendezvousChannel@7435} 
   p$ = {StandaloneCoroutine@7478} 
   _context = {CombinedContext@7483} 
   _facade = {DispatchedContinuation@7484} 
   completion = {StandaloneCoroutine@7478} 
   label = 1
   arity = 2
   shadow$_klass_ = {Class@7194} ""
   shadow$_monitor_ = -1282289382
```

Comment: where does connectJob come from?
I have an additional value in my debugger called "data" even though the variablename is something else

Comment: Also I only see the variable if i pass the same context to both launch calls. otherwise the value of that variable is "kotlin.Unit". So, I don't really understand what's happening either.

Comment: The connectJob comes from another launch further up, but I tested to remove it and it is still the same